# Is there a way to convert a python chess board into a list of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chess, python-chess

I am trying to create a neural network to play chess, but first, I need to convert the chess board to a list of integers. I am using the [python-chess](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/) module for the chess board and game. I currently have a chess board class, but cannot find a method to convert it into a list.

I have tried to use the `chess_board.epd()` method, but that returns a formatting scheme that is hard to convert.

Here is the code that I need:

```py
board = chess.Board()  # Define board object
board.convert_to_int()  # Method I need
```

Right now, with the `.epd()` method I get `"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/5P2/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq -"`

As you can see, it is very difficult to parse and convert to a list of integers as there are `/8/`'s and `/5P2/`.

The expected output is something like this (goes row by row):

`[4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... -1, -1, -1, -1,-1, -1,-1, -1, -4, -2, -3, -5, -6, -3, -2, -4]`

For example, these can be what integers map to the peices:

```
pawn - 1
knight - 2
bishop - 3
rook - 4
queen - 5
king - 6
```

And white can be positive integers and black can be negative integers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have posted the question on [Github](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/issues/404), and I found I got a more elegant solution there. It was the following:

```py
>>> import chess
>>> board = chess.Board()
>>> [board.piece_type_at(sq) for sq in chess.SQUARES]  # Get Type of piece
[4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

Note the above version does not include negatives, so here is the imporved version:

```py
def convert_to_int(board):
        l = [None] * 64
        for sq in chess.scan_reversed(board.occupied_co[chess.WHITE]):  # Check if white
            l[sq] = board.piece_type_at(sq)
        for sq in chess.scan_reversed(board.occupied_co[chess.BLACK]):  # Check if black
            l[sq] = -board.piece_type_at(sq)
        return [0 if v is None else v for v in l]

piece_type_list(chess.Board())

"""
Outpus:
[4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,
 -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -4, -2, -3, -5, -6, -3, -2, -4]
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a function to convert the chess.Board object into a matrix

```
def make_matrix(board): #type(board) == chess.Board()
    pgn = board.epd()
    foo = []  #Final board
    pieces = pgn.split(" ", 1)[0]
    rows = pieces.split("/")
    for row in rows:
        foo2 = []  #This is the row I make
        for thing in row:
            if thing.isdigit():
                for i in range(0, int(thing)):
                    foo2.append('.')
            else:
                foo2.append(thing)
        foo.append(foo2)
    return foo
```

This returns a matrix or nested lists:

Output:

```
[['r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r'], 
['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'], 
['R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R']]
```

Comment: Yeah, this converts the board to a matrix, but it doesn't turn it into a list of numbers like OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version, using the unicode() method:

```
def convert_to_int(board):
    indices = '♚♛♜♝♞♟⭘♙♘♗♖♕♔'
    unicode = board.unicode()
    return [
        [indices.index(c)-6 for c in row.split()]
        for row in unicode.split('\n')
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read the documntation of the `chess` module and created a simple abstract `Class` as you want.

```py
import chess

class MyChess(chess.Board):

    mapped = {
        'P': 1,     # White Pawn
        'p': -1,    # Black Pawn
        'N': 2,     # White Knight
        'n': -2,    # Black Knight
        'B': 3,     # White Bishop
        'b': -3,    # Black Bishop
        'R': 4,     # White Rook
        'r': -4,    # Black Rook
        'Q': 5,     # White Queen
        'q': -5,    # Black Queen
        'K': 6,     # White King
        'k': -6     # Black King
        }

    def convert_to_int(self):
        epd_string = self.epd()
        list_int = []
        for i in epd_string:
            if i == " ":
                return list_int
            elif i != "/":
                if i in self.mapped:
                    list_int.append(self.mapped[i])
                else:
                    for counter in range(0, int(i)):
                        list_int.append(0)
```

**Note:**

Uppercase letters are for white pieces and lowercase letters are for black pieces.
And 0 are for empty spaces in the chess board.

Answer (score 0):

`[(board.piece_type_at(sq) if board.piece_type_at(sq) else 0)*(-1 if board.color_at(sq)==False else 1) for sq in chess.SQUARES]`

output
`[4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -4, -2, -3, -5, -6, -3, -2, -4]`

Answer (score 0):

this is for ai model maybe

```
def preProcesser(board: chess.Board):
    chess_dict = {
            1 : [1,0,0,0,0,0],
            2 : [0,1,0,0,0,0],
            3 : [0,0,1,0,0,0],
            4 : [0,0,0,1,0,0],
            5 : [0,0,0,0,1,0],
            6 : [0,0,0,0,0,1],
            0 : [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        }
    return torch.from_numpy(np.array([np.array(chess_dict[(board.piece_type_at(sq) if board.piece_type_at(sq) else 0)])*(-1 if board.color_at(sq)==False else 1) for sq in chess.SQUARES]).astype(np.float16).reshape(-1))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure that your answer solves the problem. The OP didn't ask about `numpy` or `pytorch`, they just want a simple list.